# Juego "Try to guess the number" con número de intentos

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el ciclo termine hasta cierto numero de intentos? Y que el computador pregunte si quiero volver a jugar o no.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

 using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int num, guess, tries=0;

    cout<<"\t Wellcome to 'Guess the number'! ";
    cout<<"\n\n I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Try to guess it.";

    num = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do 
    {
        cout<<"\n\n Take a guess: "; cin>>guess;
        tries++;

        if (guess == num)
        {
            cout<<"\n Well done, you guessed it!";
            cout<<"\n You guessed it in "<<tries<<" tries.";
        }

        else if (guess < num)
        {
            cout<<" Your guess is too low...\n";
        }

        else if (guess > num)
        {
            cout<<" Your guess is too high...\n";
        }

        else if (tries == 5) 
        {
            cout<<"\n Sorry you reached the maximum number of tries.";
            cout<<"\n Game over";
        }

    } while (guess != num);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Anade un numero para la maxima "tries" y despues controlarlo en la "while", como asi: while (guess != num && tries <= maxTries)
Perdoneme, pero no me conozco C bien (tampoco espanol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es agregar `break` a la parte verifica si el juego a terminado pero debes eliminar el `else` antes del ultimo `if` ya que sino jamas entrara en esa condición pues forzosamente habrá entrado en alguno de los casos anteriores.

Quedaría así:

```
if (tries == 5) 
{
    cout<<"\n Sorry you reached the maximum number of tries.";
    cout<<"\n Game over";
    break; // <--- añades esto
}
```

`break` fuerza a salir del bucle `do..while`.

Otra opción es hacer lo que te dijo @BClayShannon en los comentarios, pero para que se vea el mensaje de Game Over, deberás eliminar el `else` también, como te explique antes.

Comment: y cómo puedo crear la opcion de jugar de nuevo o no?

Comment: Hola @Nas_04 esa es otra pregunta... pero mas o menos es algo asi: esto que tienes hecho es la función jugar, si lo mueves a una función separada y en el nivel mas alto (en main) pones un menu principal que seria otro bucle con las opciones jugar y salir. si pone jugar llamas a esta función que hiciste si pone salir das return al main.

Answer (score 0):

Nada mas quiero ampliar el comentario de B. Clary Shannon, quien tiene la razón al decir:

> Anade un numero para la maxima "tries" y despues controlarlo en la
>   "while", como asi: while (guess != num && tries <= maxTries)

Y lo puedes hacer así:

```
} while (guess != num && tries <= maxTries);
```

Así defines que solo hay un maximo de oportunidades en el juego.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

 using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int num, guess, tries=0;
    int maxTries = 5;

    cout<<"\t Wellcome to 'Guess the number'! ";
    cout<<"\n\n I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Try to guess it.";

    cout<<"\t You have 5 oportunities'! ";

    num = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do 
    {
        cout<<"\n\n Take a guess: "; cin>>guess;
        tries++;

        if (guess == num)
        {
            cout<<"\n Well done, you guessed it!";
            cout<<"\n You guessed it in "<<tries<<" tries.";
        }

        else if (guess < num)
        {
            cout<<" Your guess is too low...\n";
        }

        else if (guess > num)
        {
            cout<<" Your guess is too high...\n";
        }

        else if (tries == 5) 
        {
            cout<<"\n Sorry you reached the maximum number of tries.";
            cout<<"\n Game over";
        }

    } while (guess != num && tries <= maxTries);

    getch();
}
```